# Randomized testing of Tor options

Tags: configuration

When looking at the [Tor manpage](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en) one sees lots of different options.  They range from general options to some which are specific to relays, hidden services etc. I'm asking myself if each of those options will play well with any other. Does the Tor project some kind of randomized testing of options? Like enabling a random set of options and try to start the Tor client (I would call it option fuzzing ;)). Is this something which is worth doing and how can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say that building such an "option fuzzer" would be quite hard, because you'd have to put in a lot of domain knowledge which combinations of options should be permitted, or you'd generate lots of false positives.  Also, how do you define "working"?  I'd also say that an option fuzzer wouldn't be very useful, as opposed to fuzzers for the ports that are opened to the Internet, like OR or directory port.  Overall, a better approach would be to write a good set of unit tests for [`src/or/config.c`](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/blob/HEAD:/src/or/config.c) and friends.

However, if you want to try this anyway, please don't run these tors in the public Tor network.  You could use the `--verify-config` switch to test a configuration and exit.  Or you could [run a private Tor network using Chutney or Shadow](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorFAQ#HowdoIsetupmyownprivateTornetwork).